# Selenium WebDriver AndroidDriver TestAnAndroidWebApp or Other Sample

Tags: android, selenium, webdriver

I am familiar with the WebDriver APIs for FireFoxDriver and IEDriver, but I am new to the AndroidDriver. I'm having some kind of problem configuring my system (before I even get to using many APIs).  I've configured my system following the directions as specified in http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver#Get_Started.

The SDK, emulator and loading WebDriver on the emulator seem fine.  I imported the two projects: SimpleApp and TestAnAndroidWebApp but when I run them I get "Unable to execute dex: Java Heap Space - An out of Memory Error has Occurred.  The console also shows an error (see below.)  Suggestions as to what might be wrong?
Thanks in advance!

> [2012-02-14 09:47:36 - SimpleApp] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   (bsh.SimpleNode$1) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>   this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>   indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. When i run the project in my desktop computer(WinXP), it always throw the exception and eclipse crashes. But when i using the same Eclipse version and the same Android SDK version to run the same project in my notebook(Win7), it is everything fine. I think that this problem may due to some other environment fator. But i don't know what that is.